# how to pass/read hiveconfs variable inside hql file

Tags: hive, airflow, hive-configuration

using hive operator and passing hql file run hql file in airflow

```
hive_task = HiveOperator(
    task_id='run_hql',
    hql='/path/to/your_query.hql',
    hive_conn_id='your_hive_connection_id',
    hiveconf_jinja_translate=True,
    hiveconfs={'table_name': 'your_table_name', 'days': 5},
    dag=dag,
)
```

And hql content as below

```
-- Define parameters
SET hivevar:table_name=YOUR_DEFAULT_TABLE_NAME;
SET hivevar:days_offset=YOUR_DEFAULT_DAYS_OFFSET;

-- Use parameters in the query
SET days={{ macros.dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(days=-hivevar:days) | replace(":", "-") }};

ANALYZE TABLE edw_health.${hivevar:table_name} PARTITION(ds = '{{ days }}') COMPUTE STATISTICS;
ANALYZE TABLE edw_health.${hivevar:table_name} PARTITION(ds = '{{ days }}') COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS;
```

getting error as 'hiveconf' is undefined.

Could any one suggest if something i am missing and how to read the hive confs variable values inside hql file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `hivevar` namespace in the Hive script:

```
 ${hivevar:table_name}
```

But hiveconfs are passed as key=value in `hiveconf` namespace.

See [hive_operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.10/_api/airflow/operators/hive_operator/index.html)

Use hiveconf instead of hivevar:

```
 ${hiveconf:table_name}
```